# Git Bash: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: github, https, permissions

remote: Permission to rakeshuke/my-new-repo-ru.git denied to dilip26jan.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rakeshuke/my-new-repo-ru.git

Comment: 403 = permission denied = wrong or missing credentials used for accessing the repository. As the repository is public it seems like you are trying to push data to it. For that you need to provide a Github authentication token. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 0):

From the repo URL you provided (https://github.com/rakeshuke/my-new-repo-ru.git), I can see that your GitHub username is: rakeshuke

On your terminal run

> git config --list

Check if your name corresponds to that on the URL, if not, run this on the terminal

> git config user.name "rakeshuke"

> git config user.email "your-email"

> git config user.credential.username "rakeshuke"

Lastly, get your Personal Access Token from github.com and update it in the credential manager of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub, create a token using the following link

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Then in terminal use the **generated token instead of your password**. It worked for me.